# php cookies, how to reload the $_cookie array

Tags: php, arrays, cookies

So im using the $_cookie array in php to store the id of articles in a cart. When i remove a cookie i need to reload the page one more time so that the articles disappears from the cart. I tracked the cookies with FireBug and the Cookie disappears correctly at the first click but the article stays.
Is there a way to update/reload the $_cookie-Array without reloading the page?

setting the cookies:

```
$cookie_name = "product[".$a_id."]";
        $cookie_value = $a_id;
        setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value);
```

deleting a cookie:

```
if(isset($_GET['del_a_id'])){
    $a_id = $_GET['del_a_id'];
        setcookie ("product[".$a_id."]", "", time() - 3600);
}
```

Comment: Modify the DOM with JS to reflect how it would be on reload.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax to not refresh the page,
The ajax to check if you did well simply remove the article if this is the case in the success of the ajax request you delete the cookie

To find the cookie looks at his console.log(document.cookie)